# Internet Explorer conditional comment not closing

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm using conditional comments to include a IE7 only stylesheet.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://itmalsvmsv1:8005/searchPeople_ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-–>
```

Pretty standard, I think, but the page results blank. Seems like the comment opens but never closes and so the whole page is blanked out. Any Help?

Comment: It's not public, it's an intranet page. I'm sure that the problem is there because, removing it, it all works fine.

Comment: Can you post more code associated with it. Possibly is a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
<![endif]-–>
```

The last dash in the line is not the right kind.

Use this instead:

```
<![endif]-->
```